# Establish convergence of the series: $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Establish convergence of the series: $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-...$
The number of signs increases by one in each "block".

I have an idea. Group the series like this: $1-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6})-...$

We can show that $1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6},...$ converges to 0. I'm trying to use Dirichlet's Test. However, I'm not sure wether this sequence is decreasing.

Any idea? Or any other method to establish the convergence?

Comment: Absolute value of sums of blocks is indeed monotone decreasing. Proof is straightforward, just unpleasant to typeset.

Comment: straightforward? Can show $block_{k+1}-block_{k}<0$?

Comment: Yes, and its's not even close, fairly crude estimates will do it.

Answer (score 11):

We can see that the general term of this series is
$$a_n=(-1)^n\sum_{k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n+1}\frac{1}{k}$$
and we have 
$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\log n+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$
so 
\begin{align}|a_n|=H_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n+1}-H_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}&=\log(1+\frac{2}{n})+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})\\
&=\frac{2}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})\end{align}
hence we have
$$a_n=\frac{2(-1)^n}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$
which  allows us to conclude the convergence of the series since it's sum of two convergent series, one by alternating series test and the other by comparaison with Riemann series.

Comment: Replace every $o(1/n^2)$ by $O(1/n^2)$.

Comment: @Did  thanks for your comment.

Comment: And now, why does all this *allow us to conclude* [that] *the convergence of the series* [holds]?

Comment: @Did The series is sum of two convergent series, one by alternating series test and the other by comparaison with Riemann series. Is not it?

Comment: Spot on. Let me suggest to include this (quite neat) argument in the answer.

Comment: @Did Your suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Upvoted, as the only full answer, so far.

Answer (score 9):

If I'm not getting it wrong, your series is

$$1-\frac 1 2 -\frac 13+\frac 14+\frac 15+\frac 16-\frac 17-\frac 18-\frac 19-\frac 1{10}+++++------\dots$$

So you have $1$ plus, $2$ minuses, $3$ pluses, $4$ minuses, and so on.

We can write your series as $a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots$ where
$$\begin{align} a_0&=(-1)^0 1 \\
 a_1&=(-1)^1\sum_{k=2}^{3}\frac 1 k\\
a_2&=(-1)^2\sum_{k=4}^{6}\frac 1 k\\
a_3&=(-1)^3\sum_{k=7}^{10}\frac 1 k\\
\cdots &=\cdots \\
a_n&=(-1)^n\sum_{k=T_n+1}^{T_{n+1}}\frac 1 k\end{align}$$

Where $T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so it goes $1,3,6,10,\dots$

Now, we know that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k =\log n+\gamma+\frac 1 {2n}+O(n^{-2})$$

Thus

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{{T_n}} {{1 \over k}}  = \log n + \log \left( {n + 1} \right) - \log 2 + \gamma  + O({n^{ - 2}})  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{{T_{n + 1}}} {{1 \over k}}  = \log \left( {n + 2} \right) + \log \left( {n + 1} \right) - \log 2 + \gamma  + O({n^{ - 2}}) \cr} $$

Whence, after simplification

$$\sum\limits_{k = {T_n} + 1}^{{T_{n + 1}}} {{1 \over k}}  = \log \left( {1 + {2 \over n}} \right) + O(n^{-2})$$

Recall that $$\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$$ so

$$\sum\limits_{k = {T_n} + 1}^{{T_{n + 1}}} {{1 \over k}}  = \frac{2}{n} +O\left(\frac 1 {n^2}\right)$$

Since $$\sum (-1)^n \frac 1 n $$ and $$\sum n^{-2}$$ converge, so does your series.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} = \log n + \gamma + o(1)$. What's this? I'm a year1 maths student. I haven't seen this before...

Comment: It is a short way of saying that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}-\log n\to \gamma$$ when $n\to\infty$; where $\gamma$ is a constant, $0.577...$, known as Euler's constant. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326979/prove-that-sum-k-1-n-k-1-lnn-o1/327015#327015) you can see a proof of that.

Comment: The last expression proves nothing. By the way, note that $2/n+O(1/n^2)+o(1)$ is simply $o(1)$.

Comment: @Did What improvement do you suggest?

Comment: Rewrite the thing starting from the estimate of the $n$th harmonic number $H_n$. Note that the estimate $H_n=\log(n)+\gamma+o(1)$ fails to yield the result, one needs one more term in the asymptotic expansion of $H_n$.

Comment: @Did I see. I will correct it in a while. Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. You might want to signal right now at the beginning of the post that a corrected version is coming.

Comment: The $o(1)$ would seem to be a problem for the convergence (which I now see that @Did has noted).

Comment: @Did I edited. I hope you approve of it now =)

Comment: This looks correct (+1)

Comment: PeterT: The proof is correct now. +1.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the alternating series test if you can prove that the sum of a block goes to zero.  Block $n$ starts at $\dfrac 1{\dfrac {n(n-1)}2+1}$ and ends at $\dfrac 1{\frac {n(n+1)}2}$ and has $n$ terms.  The sum is then less than $\dfrac n{\dfrac {n(n-1)}2}=\dfrac 2{n-1}$ which goes to zero

Comment: You have also to prove the block is decreasing.

Comment: I have proved the sum of a block converges to 0. But alternating series test also requires the sum of block is a decreasing sequence. I failed to prove the sequence is decreasing...

Comment: The same argument shows the sum of a block is greater than $\frac 2{n+1}$.  A little finer work will show it is $\frac 2n+O(\frac 1{n^2})$, which is nicely decreasing.

Comment: @RossMillikan See my answer.

Comment: To show something like $2/n+O(1/n^2)$ is indeed quite needed (thus this estimate, if true, should be in the answer), but note that then, the argument winning the game is not the alternating series test.

Comment: @RossMillikan: $\frac2n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ does not ensure monotonicity. For example $\frac2{n-(-1)^n}$ is $$\left\{1,2,\frac12,\frac23,\frac13,\frac25,\dots\right\}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\underbrace{\vphantom{\frac11}+1}_{\text{length }1}
\underbrace{-\frac12-\frac13}_{\text{length }2}
\underbrace{+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16}_{\text{length }3}
\underbrace{-\frac17-\frac18-\frac19-\frac1{10}}_{\text{length }4}
\underbrace{+\frac1{11}+\frac1{12}+\frac1{13}+\frac1{14}+\frac1{15}}_{\text{length }5}-\ldots
$$
The absolute values of the terms of the same-sign block of length $n$ are from
$$
\dfrac1{n(n-1)/2+1}\quad\text{to}\quad\dfrac1{n(n+1)/2}
$$
and the sum of the block must satisfy
$$
\frac2{n+1}=\frac{n}{n(n+1)/2}\le(-1)^{n-1}\text{sum}\le\frac{n}{n(n-1)/2+1}\lt\frac2{n-1}
$$
which tends to $0$.

The absolute value of the sum of the same-sign block of length $n$ and the same-sign block of length $n+1$ is at most
$$
\frac2{n-1}-\frac2{n+2}=\frac6{(n+2)(n-1)}
$$
Thus, the sum of pairs of blocks converge absolutely and the blocks converge to $0$. Thus, the full series converges.

Comment: Very nice... +1

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Ross Millikan's answer and André Nicolas's comment, denote the $n$-th block sum (ignoring the sign) by $B_n$. Then
\begin{align}
B_n &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{k_n+n},\\
k_n &= \frac{n(n-1)}{2},\\
k_{n+1} &= k_n+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \le n^2.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
B_n - B_{n+1}
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{k_n+i} - \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac1{k_{n+1}+i}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{k_n+i} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{k_{n+1}+i} - \frac1{k_n+2n+1}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{(k_n+i)(k_{n+1}+i)} - \frac1{k_n+2n+1}\ \text{ by } (1)\\
&\ge \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{(k_n+n)(k_n+2n)} - \frac1{k_n+2n+1}\\
&= \frac{n^2}{(k_n+n)(k_n+2n)} - \frac1{k_n+2n+1}\\
&\ge \frac{1}{k_n+2n} - \frac1{k_n+2n+1}\ \text{ by } (1)\\
&> 0.
\end{align}
Hence the block sum is indeed monotonic decreasing and the alternating series test applies.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd take a different approach to it, by providing upper and lower bounds.

For an upper bound, we'll assume that all values in the positive sequences are the largest of them, and all values in the negative sequences are the smallest. That is, for instance...

$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} < \frac{3}{4}$

And

$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}>\frac{4}{10} = \frac{2}{5}$

For the positive terms, we have that the sums are bounded above by $\frac{2n+1}{n(2n+1)+1} < \frac{1}{n}$, while the negative terms' sums are bounded below by $\frac{2}{2n+1} > \frac{1}{n+1}$. As such, we can say easily that the series cannot be larger than

$$
1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 2
$$
Similarly, the positive sums are bounded below by $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and the negative sums are bounded above by $\frac{2n}{n(2n-1)+1} < \frac{1}{n-1}$. And so, the series cannot be smaller than

$$
  \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n-1}\right) = -1
$$

As such, we know that the series must be less than 2 and greater than -1, so we know that the series does not diverge, and thus we only need to show that it does not fail to converge due to oscillation. As both the positive and negative sum terms behave as $1/n$ in the limit as $n \to \infty$ (thereby preventing cyclic behaviour), we know that the series must converge.